# Cannot find Awesome DE log in icon

Tags: 13.04, awesome

I have just installed Awesome DE on Ubuntu 13.04. I logged out, but just found GNOME, GNOME(no effect), GNOME(3D). What's wrong?

I tried `sudo apt-get install awesome-de` again, it returns I have installed awesome DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (probably) have **awesome** installed. The package – for reasons beyond my understanding – ships a desktop file with `NoDisplay = true` set.

To get **awesome** to show up in your login manager, open `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` in an editor with root rights and remove the `NoDisplay = true` line. Save it, log out and you should see the option to log into **awesome**.